Make Hosts Only Edit Via Custom (not sudo) Password - To Stop Addiction
I use Firefox extensions and modifications to the hosts file in the /etc directory to block websites like Instagram, Reddit, and YouTube. However, I sometimes bypass these self-imposed restrictions and end up scrolling through those websites. I want to take it a step further by making the hosts file editable only with a custom password that is different from my sudo password. At the same time, Ubuntu should still be able to read the hosts file without any issues.
Is it possible to achieve this? Will I need third-party software? The main concern is ensuring Ubuntu can still use the hosts file without problems, especially since I have upcoming exams and can't afford distractions.
For context, I am using the latest version of Ubuntu and am relatively new to it.
Thanks for your help.

There is no version of Ubuntu called latest. And in a year it will not be what you use today. Please edit the question and give the actually version info.
